# Symfony 4 setter injection in parent class

Tags: forms, symfony, dependency-injection, request, symfony4

Just a quick question. I'm building some API. I was thinking about creating simple parent class that would deal with form requests.

So for example if you would like to easily handle form request you just extend this class and you get access to request object, request data extracted from that object and bunch of methods that do some things for you out of the box. It doesn't matter what and why exactly.

The problem is:

1. I send request through postman.
2. I try to use request object in class that extends parent class but instead of request I get null.

How do I set up the whole thing?:

Now in Symfony every controller is by default registered as a service so I override this definition like this:

```
#generic api form controller
    App\Controller\Api\ApiFormController:
      calls:
          - [setDependencies, ['@request_stack', '@App\Service\Serialization\Serializer']]
```

So as you can see I am using setter injection.

I extend above class in my other class. Let's call it PostController. So:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class ApiFormController
{
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    public $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack    
     */
    public function setDependencies(
        RequestStack $requestStack       
    ) {
        $this->request = $requestStack;       
    }
}
```

And now PostController:

```
 public function get(int $post = null)
 {
   dump($this->request); exit;
 }
```

I was expecting to get access like this and I think I understand why I don't have access to this object. I'm looking for some ideas how I could achieve this goal in cleanest possible way. I'm not expecting ready answers but hints.

I was thinking about using events to set it up in the background?
I also think it has something to do with the way I'm hooking up my controller as a service.

Comment: I don't get your question - where is the connection between `PostController` and `ApiFormController` - is it a subclass? Why don't you have a service defined for it? And why does your call definition in YML contain two parameters, but the method only uses one of them?

Comment: Let's start with last question. I removed some code to make it more clear. I just forgot to remove this other service. This doesn't matter. Connection like you mentioned is that PostController extends ApiFormController(idea mentioned in first couple of sentences). "Why don't you have a service defined for it?" - for what exactly? The whole functionality? The idea is to have a controller that I can extend and that controller would have all required services injected. It would handle by default my requests. Do you need any further explanation?

Comment: If only your parent class has a service definition, but the subclass has not, the service definition is only used for the parent class. If you want to inject services into your subclass, you have to write a service definition for it, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post: Controllers are defined as services by default and I din't change that setting so my sub class is also service by default. The only reason I have overridden this ApiFormController Service definition is because I wanted to make it call setter method automatically. If I understand correctly chapter you provided tells us about how to override parent dependencies and how to make service definitions a little bit more cleaner. I don't see how that helps. Could you be so kind and elaborate that a bit?

Comment: How should the DI container know that your subclass also needs the same dependencies as the parent controller? It does not care about whether the PHP class `PostController` is the descent of `ApiFormController` - it picks up the service definitions you declare. And if you declare no services to be injected into `PostController`, no services are injected

Comment: You are absolutely right about the way it works but(I think) that's not the case. So I do not want to inject request to child class. It is injected into parent class and child class should just inherit request object. I thought this way I can avoid injection of request into child class. I was hoping I could just "grab" existing injected object from parent class. If that makes  any sense. It is possible that I am just not explaining myself clear enough.

Comment: If you don't inject a sevice into the child class, the child class will not know about it, period. As far as I have used Symfony's DI container, it does not grab together the requested classes service defition and the definitions of all parent classes by default. And "grabbing" existing service definitions works like explained through explicitly defining the parent service in the service definition, additionally to extending the class itself

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your explanation and time here Nico. I will tinker with it not and I will let you know if I solved my issue. Thanks again!

Comment: You were right man. Awesome and thank you again. Could you post your explanation as a answer so it can be more visible to other people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of it all: Symfony does not pick up service definition for subclasses. So if you define dependencies for a class and extend it in another class, you have to define the dependencies for this second class too.

The easiest way is to use the `parent` keyword for this, so your example would work in the following way:

```
App\Controller\Api\ApiFormController:
  calls:
      - [setDependencies, ['@request_stack', '@App\Service\Serialization\Serializer']]

PostController:
  parent: App\Controller\Api\ApiFormController
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autowiring, you can use @required to make Symfony call the setter automatically. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-other-methods-e-g-setters

```
/**
 * @param RequestStack $requestStack
 * @required   
 */
public function setDependencies(
    RequestStack $requestStack       
) {
    $this->request = $requestStack;       
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I see several problems here.

1. If you want to inject dependencies in such a way you should define controller as service. You can read more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html).

Routing should be something like this:

```
# config/routes.yaml
get_something:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: App\Controller\Api\PostController:get }
```

Also, you should define PostController as service, not ApiFormController.

2. You injected RequestStack but type hint for the attribute is Request.

Instead of:

```
$this->request = $requestStack;
```

You need to use:

```
$this->request = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();
```

Comment: Sorry but you got all of it wrong. First of all I never mentioned that routing is a problem. Other thing I don't know why but you missed the part where I said that Controllers are automatically defined as services now. About request: where do you see type hint for request? Comment is wrong that's right but it is not part of the problem! Like I mentioned in comments(which you didn't read) I refactored a code a little bit to strip it out of the unnecessary code and I missed some bits and pieces. I need to have both Controllers as services and I want access to main requestStack object.